# How to fix Unauthorized error in Google App Engine with spring rest?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spring-rest

I have uploaded a spring rest project to google app engine which I made with standard app engine project in maven. When I make a request to the api I get "Error: Unauthorized" as the response. Before deploying, I have tested the apis on the local app engine server and they were returning the results as expected.

Please refer the security config as below:

```
package com.travelplanner.rest.config;

//COPY
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;

    @Bean  
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {  
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(securityDataSource);
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager; 
    }       

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);  
    }

}
```

Please refer the response header if it is helpful:

```
alt-svc →quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
cache-control →private
content-encoding →gzip
content-length →163
content-type →text/html;charset=utf-8
date →Fri, 04 Jan 2019 13:16:50 GMT
pragma →no-cache
server →Google Frontend
status →401
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
vary →Accept-Encoding
www-authenticate →Basic realm="Realm"
x-cloud-trace-context →1152278a96141cf513a5830f6dcf4f92;o=1
```

I have basic security in spring setup and even when I make a request with the correct credentials I get the above error.

Api: https://exoticatravels-1543931266259.appspot.com/api/users/travel-plan/1

User: xlz@wwe.com
pass: thepass

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your spring security config / chain if possible

Comment: @Dominik I have added the securityconfig.java